# How to Read and do changes in HtmlTextWriter

Tags: asp.net, htmltextwriter

In an ASP.NET site, I am rendering a GridView control to export it's details in a excel file

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel")
Dim stringWrite As System.IO.StringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter
Dim htmlWrite As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite)
gridviewObject.RenderControl(htmlWrite)
Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString())
Response.End()
```

Now, it's getting rendered,but the gridview uses few images to beautify the data.
While exporting the data I don't want to show images in excel.
So I want to find the  tag and want to replace it by blank string.

Can anybody tell me how I can do that?